# Should we be using the /users tag? And how do we account for /accounts?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users) feels a bit vague to me. It covers several related topics, including:

- user account metadata (password, shell, …), e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204612/shell-script-to-change-user-shell) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201833/how-to-cat-etc-shadow-on-an-hmc) [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191663/any-concerns-with-using-high-uid-numbers-3000-on-rhel5)
- user account databases, e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199220/how-to-loop-over-users) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197124/why-are-there-many-accounts-im-the-only-user)
- privileges of a user (the files they can write, etc.), e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203869/killall-processes-under-a-user) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196932/how-to-limit-the-number-of-active-logins-per-user)
- file ownership, e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201694/find-files-created-by-a-particular-user); often [chown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chown) is used instead

We also have [accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounts), which covers user account metadata and databases. I don't know when to use [accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounts) and when to use [users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users) for this meaning (except that [accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounts) can also apply to groups).

Should we split [users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users)? If so, should we unify one of the meanings with [accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounts)?

As for [group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group), it feels more tame to me. But it should be renamed to [groups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/groups).

Comment: How about [tag:user-accounts] for meta-data and databases, [tag:privileges] for those and *nothing* for ownership? Then [tag:accounts] could be merged in to [tag:user-accounts].

Comment: @guntbert That might work. I've been wondering if we should have a [tag:file-metadata] tag covering permissions, ownership, timestamps and so on, but it's not discoverable enough.

Comment: Next idea in that lane: create [tag:file-metadata] and make [tag:privileges] and [tag:inodes] ... aliases of it.

Comment: @guntbert [tag:permissions], not [tag:privileges]. And inodes and names are sufficiently peculiar that they need a tag separate from [tag:file-metadata]. Another approach would be to consider permissions to be part of ownership (after all, with ACL, group ownership turns into a permission). Just tossing ideas out for now, I'm not sure which approach is best.

Answer (score 3):

I think we could get away of groups, accounts, user(s) and group(s) if we used a single [user-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-management) for all questions about UID/GID and related topics, as they pertain the user administration of the kernel/system. Other usages, like databases, web servers and the like, that are not directly related with the user/group of the (file)system itself should use their respective applications tags, like [mysql](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache), [pam](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pam), etc.

Is the most simple solution I can find, which would have the most desired effect and prevents confusion.

Comment: what about NSS?

Comment: @hildred there's already the [tag:nsswitch] tag

Answer (score 0):

I do associate [users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users) with, `users` in `/etc/group`. IIRC this used to be the initial group account for when new user accounts were made (before the practise of making a group with the username for each user became widespread).

At least [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18198/gid-current-primary-supplementary-effective-and-real-group-ids) questions seems to use it that way.

I don't think that that once case warrants keeping that tag around. If there are more such cases a more generic [initial-group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/initial-group) would be more appropriate (i.e. describing its function not necessarily the actual name used). During a re-tag action one could retag [users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users) to this for appropriate questions and tally at the end to see whether [initial-group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/initial-group) should be a keeper.

Comment: You mean the group called `users` often present on default Linux installation? A logical tag name would be `users-group`, but that's an extremely specific topic, I don't see it warranting a tag. The question you cite is not about that: in that question, `users` is just an example.

Comment: @Gilles yes that is the one I mean, and what the question I quote refers to. It is what in the man page is called the intiial group. I am not sure if it warrents keeping at all. I did not count up-front, but proposed the process of first renaming and then deciding on deletion after it is clear how many of this particular use cases there are. Instead of just removing the [tag:users] and not being able to find thiem once you would realise there are enough to warrent the tag. I would not use `users-group`, as some distro might not use/have used `users` for the common initial group.

Comment: What do you mean by “common initial group”? Do you mean the default primary group? [tag:default-primary-group] would be a better name. But that too is an overly specific topic, I think we can live with just [tag:group] and something like [tag:user-accounts]. We don't even have a tag for [tag:primary-group] or [tag:supplemental-groups].

Comment: @Gilles I got `initial group` from `man useradd`, but [tag:default-primary-group] would probably be better. I have only retagged some 20 questions in one action and I could preview all before I started. With the 571 [tag:users] that is really feasable, if a retag of this uses is done to just [tag:group] and afterwards you realise you had e.g. 50 of these specific cases and decide they warrant their own tag, you would have to separate them from [tag:group]. That is more difficult to do than changing or removing [tag:default-primary-group] afterwards if there are not enough Qs for that tag

Comment: It is just how I would go about this, not knowing up front how many of these uses of [tag:users] are there going to be.

Answer (score 0):

I could be oversimplifying this:

Users - Attached to a human

Accounts - Not Attached to a human

User in a database would be accounts since it is overshadowed by account used by the database itself.  Hopefully, we aren't running our services as personal users anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to disagree with DarkSheep, As much as it would be nice to have a good unix-wide distinction between users and accounts (bob is a user, apache is an account) this is not a distinction that really exists outside a small number of administrative tools. The confusion between users (Bob, a man who has less hair than he wishes), user accounts (bob, the login for the man who wants more hair), pseudo-users (the thing the computer thinks is out there, maybe), and pseudo-user accounts (the user account set aside for the web server) is not well defined on a truly global scale (although some distributions are trying to draw a line in the sand)

If we were to adopt site specific definitions (which I think would be a good thing as long as we recognise that these definitions are not fully accepted) I would propose the following:

User: PEBKAC.

- System User Account: The association of data identifying a user returned by `pwgent` including UID, GID, username, and related information, but specifically not including password related information.
- Application User Account: any user account used by an application that is not returned by pwgent.
- Pseudo-user Account: Any special case of System User Account that does not have a corresponding User.
- Regular User Account: Any System User Account associated either with an individual or organization.

Don't even get me started on groups Which are an even bigger mess with:

- User group:

  1. organization for supporting users
  2. the group with the same name as the user
  3. a group containing real pebkac users (which sometimes is called users)
- Group user: a user that is a member of a specific group
- Administrative group: a group of users (pebkac) that have permissions based on group membership.
- system group: a group without real users (ie bin, games, lpr)
- system user group (apache)

Feel free to improve this.